# can anyone let me know what is the issue in my docker file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

i need a container running with java installed in it and i want to expose the port 8090.

Here is the Docker file i have written to achieve this.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

ENV VERSION 8
ENV UPDATE 152
ENV BUILD 16
ENV SIG aa0333dd3019491ca4f6ddbe78cdb6d0

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-${VERSION}-oracle

# install jre
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get upgrade -qqy --no-install-recommends && \
  apt-get install curl unzip bzip2 -qqy && \
  mkdir -p "${JAVA_HOME}" && \
        curl --silent --location --insecure --junk-session-cookies --retry 3 \
          --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie;" \
          http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/"${VERSION}"u"${UPDATE}"-b"${BUILD}"/"${SIG}"/jre-"${VERSION}"u"${UPDATE}"-linux-x64.tar.gz \
        | tar -xzC "${JAVA_HOME}" --strip-components=1 && \
  apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove -y curl unzip bzip2 && \
  apt-get autoclean && apt-get --purge -y autoremove && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" 1 && \
        update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javaws" 1 && \
        update-alternatives --set java "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" && \
        update-alternatives --set javaws "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/javaws"

EXPOSE 8090
```

Using the Dockerfile i was able to successfully build the image and i have pushed to my account in hub.docker.com

but when i run try to run the container using the following command , The Container was not running.

i broked my head analyzing the root cause more than 2 hours i was not able to find the problem.

I know i am missing something silly, can anyone have a look and point the mistake i am doing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the command you are using to run the container?

Comment: And also post the exact error message you are getting.

Comment: Why are you creating your own image if you want Java? Why not use a pre-built image? E.g.: https://hub.docker.com/r/isuper/java-oracle/tags/ If there are certain reasons for creating your own, you might find [their dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/isuper/java-oracle/~/dockerfile/)

Comment: Sorry, first link was deprecated: https://hub.docker.com/r/sgrio/java-oracle/

Comment: @k0pernikus As per you input i tried to use the images in the link .  docker run --name docjavaapp1234  sgrio/java-oracle:jre_8_unlimited . even this didnt bring my containers up. can you please verify iwheather it works for you ?

Comment: I don't use that java image myself. My comment was supposed to be a pointer to look up pre-existing images on docker hub. You could ask a new question about getting a certain image to run in a specific way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Dockerfile is missing an ENTRYPOINT or CMD instruction. They define what command is run when starting the container.

[Reference CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

[Reference ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response samprog , i added                                 
   ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]   and builded again still same issue . what else may be the issue ?

Comment: The container runs as long as the process you've started with the ENTRYPOINT or CMD instruction exists. If the process stops, the container stops. /bin/bash is not really a daemon or process that's continuously running. What service do you want to be reached on port 8090? I suggest you change your ENTRYPOINT or CMD to the command that starts said service.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define a ENTRYPOINT or CMD.

Some useful links:

- [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)
- https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#known-issues-run